# How to make SQL Management Studio see new table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I am using SQL server 2008. If I am working on the Management Studio's query analyser, and I go ahead and create a new table or view, then the SSMS does not see the newly created object for intellisense.

What do I do to make SSMS see and autosuggest from the newly created tables/views too?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Have you tried to refresh the intellisense cache

Edit -> Intellisense -> Refresh Local Cache (**<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>**)

Comment: Wow, that was nicely tucked away SSMS option :p Thanks!

Comment: I use ApexSQLRefactor. Apparently, Ctrl-Shift-R tells Apex to do an "Intelligent Rename"... FWIW....

Comment: Works for SQL prompt

Answer (score 12):

Go to the menus:

```
Edit > Intellisense > Refresh local cache
```

or press the shortcut key:   `Ctrl-Shift-R`